# Why use $JAVA_HOME or $AIR_HOME instead of just $PATH?

Tags: java, air, environment-variables

I know what's `$JAVA_HOME`, `$AIR_HOME`, etc., I know how to set them up. In fact I'm setting them up in every virtual environment I ever initialize for work with Java or Adobe AIR but I don't understand why I should. My question is more around what would be the consequences of ignoring `$*_HOME` variables and just using the binaries provided by system (in `$PATH`).

Is it used for anything other than finding the correct version of binaries? Applications never seem to use it for anything else and it's the responsibility of a package maintainer, the system administrator and the user to have those available in `$PATH`. There are convenient virtual environment managers that let the users switch easily between environments and select a saved `$PATH` preset that points to the correct version of a given binary for given user session. While it's usually possible to write "onSwitch" hooks that set custom environment variables, it always requires additional work.

It's been suggested that it helps a forked app to run the same version of a binary as its parent but it's already taken care of as both processes should run the binary from `$PATH` and `$PATH` is inherited by the child process from parent.

What's the reason for developers of projects like Tomcat and Gradle or Adobe AIR to rely on `$*_HOME` variables instead of what `$PATH` provides? Where that convention comes from and why is it still used?

Comment: Which Java developers? I've never seen it.

Comment: Most of the tools use it. Maven, Gradle, application servers, etc. This allows a consistency in the versions used. If you launch one app with JAVA_HOME, then that app launches another app with the same JAVA_HOME, hence both apps use the same java version.

Comment: I started to think I made a mistake asking this as many people seem attached to that variable for whatever reason. Other than that, if I run an app in one environment and it runs another app it's in the same environment - still no need for artificial variables when there's $PATH.

Comment: @user207421 I've seen it in Tomcat and Gradle for example, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

i guess as long as you only run a single application or multiple applications that all rely on the same JDK/JRE version, you are fine with just $PATH. But if you have multiple applications that rely on different JDK/JRE versions, the $*_HOME vars come in handy. So for example you could have a JAVA 8 application and a legacy application that still uses JAVA 6 for example, run on the same machine by configuring their $*_HOME vars differently.

you also may have problems with open source applications that rely on those environment variables, if you don't have them set.

Comment: What's the benefit of running the up-to-date and a legacy application in the same environment? I can easily set up two virtual environments to run JAVA 6 and 8 apps separately and those still would only need their respective `$PATH` variables. There are many maintenance benefits of doing so.

Comment: I maintain a fork of one such open source application (relying on `$*_HOME`) at work and I refactored it to use `$PATH` to make the maintenance easier, there are no issues but I wonder whether I should push that change upstream.

Comment: Well, its not always possible to use virtual environments, for example if you use license bound third party software.

Comment: How come? Whatever you install in a virtual environment should access all resources transparently just as it would if it wasn't in a virtual environment, including your license bound 3rd party software. It's not that I can't install something that uses `$*_HOME` in a virtual environment, on a contrary, I can and I do. The issue is that I have to configure it extra to set that variable every time I install it. And it's because said software tries to determine correct absolute paths on its own and fails while the perfectly usable `$PATH` variable seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

As far as I know, it's because of convenience and safety(?).

For example, let's say your java directory is pretty long. C:\Program Files\a\b\c\d\e (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201,  you set path so that you can easily access exe files in the 'bin' folder. And then you wanted to access exe files in the 'bin1' folder of Java, then you have to set another long path with semicolons to distinguish them. And then you wanted to add 'bin2' folder in the path. It will not only take your time, but you might make mistakes with your typing. (My pure assumption. I should come up with better examples. But can't think of any right now. )

By setting %JAVA_HOME%, it is convenient and safer to set environmental variables. 
you can just add %JAVA_HOME%bin    %JAVA_HOME%bin1   %JAVA_HOME%bin2  instead of typing long paths.

Probably, different OS has different styles of setting paths. (I assume) a long time ago, people used it like this with old OS, and possibly it became some kind of convention or a habit.  (I think $JAVA_HOME came up because people had a hard time setting up paths before. )

I also had similar thoughts like you, and I like your curiosity and reasoning so I wanted to help you with my limited knowledge. Hope mine helps tiny bit. (Also I wish I understood your question.)

Comment: I understand convenience but for me it honestly seems the opposite. Can you give an example of a scenario where you actually want to mix executables from `$*_HOME/bin` with those from `$*_HOME/bin1`?

Comment: @cprn  my example was bad. lol .  Just like you, I don't use HOME thing anymore, I just use path. At the beginning, I used %home% because I thought I had to use it.  I remember setting path for 'bin' folder, and some other folder but it wasn't java. I forgot what it was. Maybe If you have  many java version (for testing purposes, I actually have many  versions in my work computer) ,maybe I can set it %java_home% , I have many java versions under java folder, so the common path I would set it has %home%, but the rest with path. like %JAVA_HOME%JAVA-7\bin; %JAVA_HOME%Java-8\bin

Comment: @cprn   I think some people can use it like that, but not for me haha I only set paths, when I have a new computer or when I re-install os or something. I don't do it often. but maybe for someone who does this all the time, %home% varaible could be handy. Maybe!